# In PHP, why do I have to execute the removeChild method twice on a DOMNode from which I have just removed the style-attribute?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a script in PHP which removes empty paragraphs from an HTML file. The empty paragraphs are those `<p></p>` elements without textContent.

**HTML File with Empty Paragraphs:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!--
This page is used with remove_empty_paragraphs.php script.
This page contains empty paragraphs. The script removes the empty paragraphs and
writes a new HTML file.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <!-- Below is an empty paragraph. -->
        <p><span></span></p>
        <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
        <!-- Below is another empty paragraph. -->
        <p class=MsoNormal><b></b></p>
        <p style=''></p>
        <p>
            <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:5.0pt;color:navy;mso-ansi-language:EN-`US'></span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**First Attempt:**

```
$html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$html->loadHTMLFile("HTML File with Empty Paragraphs.html");
$pars = $html->getElementsByTagName("p");

/* removeChild foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->textContent == "") {
        $par->parentNode->removeChild($par);
    }
}

$html->saveHTMLFile("HTML File WithOut Empty Paragraphs.html");
```

**This succeeds** to:

- remove empty paragraphs without the style-attribute,

**but fails** to:

- remove empty paragraphs with the
  style-attribute.

So I insert the removeStyleAttribute foreach-loop before the removeChild foreach-loop. (I do not mind removing the style-attributes of nonempty paragraphs.)

**Second Attempt:**

```
$html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$html->loadHTMLFile("HTML File with Empty Paragraphs.html");
$pars = $html->getElementsByTagName("p");    

/* removeStyleAttribute foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->hasAttribute("style")) {
        $par->removeAttribute("style");
    }
}

/* removeChild foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->textContent == "") {
            $par->parentNode->removeChild($par);
    }
}

$html->saveHTMLFile("HTML File WithOut Empty Paragraphs.html");
```

**This succeeds** in:

- removing the style-attributes from empty paragraphs which have the style attribute.
- removing empty paragraphs that do not have the style-attributes.

**But fails!** to:

- *remove those empty paragraphs from which the style-attributes were
  removed.*

So I have to have two removeChild foreach-loops, one after the other.

**Third Attempt:**

```
$html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$html->loadHTMLFile("HTML File with Empty Paragraphs.html");
$pars = $html->getElementsByTagName("p");

/* removeStyleAttribute foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->hasAttribute("style")) {
        $par->removeAttribute("style");
    }
}

/* First removeChild foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->textContent == "") {
        $par->parentNode->removeChild($par);
    }
}

/* Second removeChild foreach-loop, identical to the first removeChild foreach-loop */
foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->textContent == "") {
        $par->parentNode->removeChild($par);
    }
}

$html->saveHTMLFile("HTML File WithOut Empty Paragraphs.html");
```

**This works perfectly!**, but it is weird to have two identical loops, one right after the other.

I also tried to use only one loop for everything.

**Fourth Attempt:**

```
$html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$html->loadHTMLFile("HTML File with Empty Paragraphs.html");
$pars = $html->getElementsByTagName("p");  

foreach ($pars as $par) {
    if ($par->textContent == "") {
        if ($par->hasAttribute("style")){
            $par->removeAttribute("style");
        }
        $par->parentNode->removeChild($par);
    }
}

$html->saveHTMLFile("HTML File WithOut Empty Paragraphs.html");
```

**This succeeds** to:

- remove empty paragraphs without the
  style-attribute,

**but fails** to:

- remove the style-attribute from empty paragraphs that have it.
- remove empty paragraphs with the style attribute.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, (or maybe it is) but http://htmlpurifier.org/ maybe something worth looking into. Just figured I would mention it, incase you never heard about it!

Comment: Are you aware of the typo at `if ($par->hasAttribute("syle")){`? "syle" -> "style".

Comment: For me, your setup works (tentatively): http://codepad.org/Di5YAez7 - Maybe you are missing something else? Could you post a minimum HTML sample that reproducibly fails for you? (For example, note that `textContent` could contain whitespace and you do not check for that.)

Comment: Works for me too with just the first code section only. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @Andy E, I fixed the typo, thanks. But it still does not work.

Comment: @Tomalak, then it must be Netbeans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list returned by getElementsByTagName is dynamic: removing nodes from the document also removes them from the list. And since foreach doesn't know the list changed, it'll happily move to the next item - which is actually *two* items down because the DOMNodeList was rearranged. Some of the <p> tags were just plain skipped.

Solution: use a for loop (with $pars->item(X) and $pars->length) instead of a foreach, but only increment if a node was *not* deleted. (Or always increment and backtrack if one was deleted.)

Separately: the last <p> (with the large <span>) wasn't deleted because of the whitespace around the <span>. Use trim() to get rid of it.

See also my reply in http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=121114&p=623974.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tomalak says it might have something to do with the whitespace.
Try disabling "preserveWhiteSpace":

```
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = false
```

*hmm I'm new here, how do I send in my answer as a comment and not as an answer?*

Comment: @Brik, none of the paragraphs had any whitespace. I am using a small test file I made in Netbeans,